# Scala multiple implicit conversions?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I don't understand the apparent contradictory behavior I'm seeing in the following code (Scala 2.9):

```
class Pimp1(val x : Double) {
  def pluss(that : Pimp1) = x + that.x
  def <(that : Pimp1) = x < that.x
}

object Pimp1 {
implicit def d2pimp(d : Double) = new Pimp1(d)
implicit def d2pimp(od : Option[Double]) = new Pimp1(od.get)
} 

object Scratch2 extends App {
    import Pimp1._

    5.0.pluss(Some(5.0))
    5.0 < Some(5.0)
}
```

The line '5.0.pluss(Some(5.0))' compiles, but the line after it does not compile with the following error message:

> overloaded method value < with alternatives:   (x: Double)Boolean    (x: Float)Boolean    (x: Long)Boolean    (x: Int)Boolean    (x: Char)Boolean    (x: Short)Boolean    (x: Byte)Boolean  cannot be applied to (Some[Double])

If I add explicit < operator to the Pimp class that takes an Option[Double]:

```
def <(that : Option[Double]) = x < that.get
```

Everything compiles fine.

Now, the way I understand Scala implicit conversion rules, this makes perfect sense:

1. The compiler understands that there's no '<' operator on Double that accepts Option[Double]
2. It considers the implicit conversion to Pimp1.
3. If Pimp1 has a suitable operator, it works, otherwise, it generates an error.
4. Importantly, this demonstrates that the compiler does **not** consider applying a second (available) implicit conversion, from Option[Double] to Pimp.

This is how I expected things to work.

However, this seems to be contradicted by the first example, where:

1. The compiler sees that there's no pluss method on Double.
2. The compiler tries the implicit conversion to Pimp, which does have such a method.
3. However, in order to make the operator work, the compiler has to apply a second implicit conversion, on the argument, to convert it to Pimp.

According to the logic above, this should not compile, but it does. Do the implicit conversion rules treat non-existing methods and non-matching methods differently?

Comment: It's interesting, because if you reverse it, it works: Some(5.0) < 5.0

Answer (score 5):

This makes sense to me.  The first one, that works goes like this:

Does Double have a pluss method?  No, can we implicitly convert it to something that does?  Yes.  Ok, now I want to apply the pluss method.  Does it take an Option?  No. Can I implictly convert Option to soemthing that it does take? yes.

The second one goes like this:

Does Double have a < method?  Yes.  Does it take an Option?  No.  can I implicitly convert Option to something that < does take?  No.

Comment: Right. The scala compiler does not try to find an implicit conversion for an object already having the required method. Option does not have comparison so Some(5.0) < 0 works.